# Table valued function VS Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, select, best-practices, tuning

There's a function that :

- returns only 1 row
- has only 1 parameter
- has multiple joins on different tables, each only to  return a single scalar value
- is called only once at each login of a web application

It currently is written in c# linq-to-sql and takes 150-300ms to execute.

After re-writing it in SQL using a very simple `SELECT` statement, it takes 30ms to execute.

Now I want to encase this select in a database function, what is the best (fastest execution) way to do so ?

1. Make a view and at every call do something like  `select * from viewXX where id=123`
2. Make a stored procedure
3. Make a table-valued function

[image: SSMS]

Are there any tricks I could take advantage of in such a case ?

Here is an example of what the query looks like

```
declare @id int=162;
select top 1 i.id, i.name, itd.description,
(select top 1 case when count(*)>0 then '1' else '0' end from category where category_desc=itd.description) "HasCategory",
(select top 1 number from wheels where wheel_item_id=i.id) "WheelCount"
from items i left items_desc itd on i.id=itd.itemid where i.id=@id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data changes infrequently, package the fast-running SELECT as a view and [define an index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) on it.

An indexed view comes with some restrictions which minimally limits flexibility in future changes. There is nothing terribly bad, however.

If the data changes very often, and updates are performance-critical, the extra time to maintain the view may be a concern, but no more than for any other index.